# C# setting custom names for ComVisible class methods?

Tags: c#, .net, com

For example I have a ComVisible class, which has a method Test:

```
[ComVisible]
public class ComTest {
    public void Test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But in COM clients like JScript/VBScript I want to call Test method as SomeOtherName like so:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("<ProgId_Goes_Here>");
obj.SomeOtherName(); // Calling Test method here
```

Is it possible?

And also for example I have ComVisible class with two methods with different signatures:

```
[ComVisible]
public class ComTest {
    public int Test(int a) {
        // ...
    }

    public string Test(string a) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But in COM clients I want to call both methods based on the arguments like so:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("<ProgId_Goes_Here>");
obj.SomeOtherName("Hello!"); // Calling Test(string)
obj.SomeOtherName(10);       // Calling Test(int)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use the `ProgIdAttribute` for the public "class" name, well, that's called a progid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2 but you can't support two methods with the same name.

Comment: Just solve this the exact same way you would in C#, embedding ComTest inside a public class as a private field whose instance you create in the constructor.  Use the names you like, avoiding overloads, and make it [ComVisible(true)].  The methods and properties are just a single line of code, calling the equivalent ComTest method/property.

Comment: @SimonMourier the compiler says that ProgIdAttribute is only valid on classes not on methods.

Comment: Yes ProgIdAttribute is for the class, like I said, not for the methods.